# System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl, jenkins, tls1.2

I've looked this up and saw a lot of threads here discussing this, however I can't quite figure it out. I am using a virtual machine to run a set of tests on Jenkins (written in C#) that are sending Http Web Requests to register, login etc etc. I am not very knowledgeable about the infrastructural part (I mean I'm a developer in test), however I know that the certificates on the servers used are valid as I have checked.

It pops up randomly in the logs and not always at the same place in the code.

System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: Wonder if those client certificates are added to the web requests.

Comment: Are you opening more than one connection at a time?  Most servers do not allow multiple connections from same IP address.  So you may not be closing one connection before opening a second connection.

Comment: @jdweng This issue has been linked to infrastructure setup. But to answer your question, I was only opening one connection at a time which closes after a 100ms.